# Why is the discriminant of a number field well-defined?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$ and $z_1,\dots,z_n$ a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$. It is clear that we can find another basis $y_1,\dots,y_n$ so, why $\Delta_K$ is independent of our choice of basis?

Comment: Any other basis will differ from the first by an invertible linear transformation in your $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathcal{O}_K$, that is an invertible matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Such a matrix has determinant equal $1$ or $-1$. Hence, the discriminant is independant of the choice of the basis.

Comment: If such a matrix has determinant $-1$ then why does the discriminant not change?

Comment: @Ninja likely because the discriminant is the square of the relevant determinant

Comment: This comes from the fact that if we have a relation $(\alpha _i)=M\cdot (\beta _i)$ where $M\in M_d(\mathbb{Q} )$ then $\operatorname{disc}(\alpha _i)=\det (M)^2\operatorname{disc}(\beta _i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice exercise in linear algebra: let $\langle,\rangle$ be a bilinear pairing on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $v_1',\ldots, v_n'$ be two bases for $V$, let $M$ be the change of basis matrix, and define the matrices $A=(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle)_{i,j}$ and $A'=(\langle v_i',v_j'\rangle)_{i,j}$. Then show that $A' = M^{tr}AM$. Taking determinants, you get ${\rm det}\;A' = ({\rm det}\;M)^2\cdot{\rm det}\;A$. So in your situation, if the two bases generate the same lattice over $\mathbb{Z}$, then $M$ is invertible over the integers, hence its determinant is invertible in the integers, i.e. is $\pm 1$, and $A$ and $A'$ have the same determinant.

Depending on how you defined the discriminant of a number field, you might have to do Exercise 2: define a pairing on $K$ such that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is an integral basis, the above matrix $A$ is the discriminant of $K$.